# Camera is not centered to Game object when attached

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

This might be a really noobie question, but I attached the camera as a child of the player and the transform is set to (0,0). When I run in the editor the camera is off centered. If I build the game it is the way I wanted. Is there a reason for this happening?

Edit: I just face palm myself. Please check your scales and bar

Credit to: @Ruzihm for fixing my dum mistake

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing it being off center in the editor. This is in the **Game** view, correct?

Comment: Sure I will and yes it is in the game view. I havent really noticed until now.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scroll bars at the bottom and right of the game view panel, it seems like 1. the view is zoomed in so not everything is visible and 2. the horizontal scroll bar isn't centered.

Recommended fix:

1. Slide the scale selector all the way to the left

OR

2. Move the horizontal scrollbar to be centered.

Comment: Omg I feel so dum now